# How to structure django admin for multiple users

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm still a complete newbie on Django, so now I'm a little bit lost on what I could do to structure my server to suit my needs.

The situation is like this: my Django admin could be accessed by the admin and multiple users. Each user can add multiple item to the server, and the server will only allow them to retrieve, modify and delete item added by them and not the other users. They will also have some custom option they can pick: like receiving notifications through emails or another channels. Meanwhile, admin can see all items, and have a filter to see all items added by one user and all users's custom option.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can user `group`. (docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization)). But if you just want to show item from login user, you can use `get_queryset()` in your admin.

Answer (score 1):

take a look here. this is where i started with custom user models. https://wsvincent.com/django-custom-user-model-tutorial/

Django has builtin user models with basic fields like username email and password and authentication. The above link will help you create custom user models and it will be a good place to start